# Leaking portable air conditioning unit

Tags: air-conditioning

I have had this Delta portable air con from Aldi for several years.  It puts a tube out of the window and collects water in a side bucket.  It has worked well albeit noisy but not needed often so in that sense nearly new.   Recently the bucket does not fill up and instead leaks onto the floor below.  Can these units be repaired either by myself or by asking an engineer.  Or is is better to buy a new one even though they are quite pricy?  Thanks, Colin

Comment: I would inspect the condensate collection setup carefully, including disassembling parts if needed, to ascertain how the condensate gets to the bucket and where the failure point is. Then I would fix it myself if possible. You might call the manufacturer and wade through the bureaucracy until you can talk to a technician, who may be able to point you in the right direction if it is a common problem. You might be able to get an exploded diagram of the unit, with a parts list, that might help you also.

Comment: Do you mean DELLA?  Delta is not a brand of air conditioner unless you are looking for a $20,000 industrial tier unit to cool a server room or process.

Comment: I'm not very good at DIY Jimmy but might have a go particularly if I can find a manual.  Definitely Delta Harper - probably an Aldo own brand and probably a German manufacturer hiding the real brand.